# When does this all start to come together?

Tags: ruby

I'm learning how to program for the first time, (with Ruby), because I want to eventually build a web application. I am understanding it well, and am halfway through 2 different tutorials, but have a major question...

I have learned so much about objects, methods, strings, etc, but so far the tutorials I've gone through have made ZERO mention of actually integrating it with the front end of a website, or "embedding" the code in HTML. So my question is, how in the heck does all of this translate to actually interacting with a website and user commands? I am failing to see the big picture here, and could really use some guidance.

Am I crazy for wondering what is going on here?!

Comment: Don't learn "Ruby". Don't "learn" a particular web framework. Pick a task that you want to accomplish, and get help on accomplishing it. Trying to learn "all" of Ruby or whatever all at once does not give you positive feedback during your efforts, and also does not help you remember it nearly as much as if you make mistakes and fix them yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It great that you have started learning Ruby! But Ruby in it self is simply a programming language. I think you wan't to check out Rails!

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

Rails is written in Ruby and a lot of what you will write will be Ruby so you will probably get started quickly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I intend to look into Rails, but I thought getting a foundation in Ruby first would help me out (long term). Will diving into Rails without knowing Ruby perfectly first make things too confusing for me? I feel like I should know the language of the framework before attempting to use the framework...

Comment: I learned Ruby through Rails, for me that worked fine because you feel like you are actually able to DO stuff! I think it is good to learn both Ruby and Ruby on Rails at the same time. That ways you can apply what you learn about Ruby right away at the same time you understand Rails a lot better when you understand Ruby.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't call it in HTML. HTML is not a language. HTML is an output format designed for web.

It's that simple.

In your "simple" ruby programs, the output of your code is shown on `STDOUT` - console, screen, etc.

Server powered with ruby interpreter translates your ruby code and presents it to the client as HTML. You define which files should get "translated" by specifying an extension (in rails) and surrounding your code with `code tags`.

#### Example

Here is a simple webrick example written in pure ruby

```
# in server.rb
#
require 'webrick'
server = WEBrick::HTTPServer.new(:Port=>8080)

trap 'INT' do server.shutdown end

class Dog
  attr_accessor :name
  def initialize(name)
    self.name = name
  end
  def bark
    "#{name} is barking!"
  end
end

dog = Dog.new("Fido")

server.mount_proc('/bark'){ |req, resp|
    resp['Content-Type'] = 'text/html'

    resp.body = "#{dog.bark}"
}

server.mount_proc('/run') do |req,resp|
    dog.instance_eval do
      def run_away
        "#{name} is running away..."
      end
    end

    resp['Content-Type'] = 'text/html'
    resp.body = "#{dog.run_away}"
end

server.start
```

Run `ruby server.rb` and go to `localhost:8080/run` and `localhost:8080/bark` to see the results.

#### Edit - Sinatra Example

If you find the webrick example hard to understand - check out [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/)!

```
# in sinatra_example.rb
require 'sinatra'

class Dog
  attr_accessor :name
  def initialize(name)
    self.name = name
  end
  def bark
    "#{name} is barking!"
  end
end

fido = Dog.new("Fido")

get '/bark' do
  fido.bark
end

get '/run' do
  fido.instance_eval do
    def run_away
      "#{name} is running away!"
    end
  end

  fido.run_away

end
```

Comment: Thank you. It's hard to understand even what that is doing or means since I am so new, but I will keep this page bookmarked and refer to it. Thanks for your time

Comment: @JeffH.  hey, I've added Sinatra example for you - it's simpler than the webrick one. Sinatra is some pretty cool DSL.

Comment: Thank you, that is much easier to understand!

Answer (score 2):

At the risk of scaring you off, to learn how to write web applications (properly) you will need to learn:

- the language you will be writing in (ruby)
- your application framework (rails? or sinatra?)
- HTML
- CSS
- javascript
- the HTTP protocol, that underlies communcation between browsers and servers

But, you don't need to learn all of one of these before diving into the next.

I recommend, while you are learning ruby, having a play with at least one of the simpler frameworks e.g. [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/).  That way you can feel like you are actually learning how to write web applications.

You could also play with rails of course, but at least in terms of learning how to write web applications, it can be a little daunting.  It can be hard for a newcomer to tell the difference between the pecularities of ruby and the peculiarities of rails.